# Exterior siding rot

Tags: wood, exterior, siding, rot, paneling

[image]

Can anyone please tell me what this type out outdoor siding is called. It looks like wood but it’s not. We need to replace portions of it. Thank you!

Comment: Take a panel out. Examine it more closely, saw a bit off it & check the cut. In that photo it could literally be anything that a plank shape could be made of.

Comment: A closer shot would be helpful. There was a type of composite siding made in the 70’s & 80’s by LP that had a horrid reputation clap board ? It had a paper like film over the composite material. There were many lawsuits in the PNW as the stuff did not last long here LP had to pay large sums to settle the suits, that would be my best guess without higher res photos. Downvote reversed, no comment on the reason why downvoted gets an up vote from me.

Comment: Would be hard to match new and old without it sticking out, if just done by pieces.  If a section is small might be better to replace a whole section with similar looking siding, without worry about matching pieces.